# Unable to figure out the post request parameter

Tags: python, api, python-requests, xmlhttprequest, httpx

I'm trying to query the following [website](https://r.cnki.net/kns/brief/result.aspx?dbprefix=gwkt)

By choosing the advanced search as below and query that pattern `QW=部队`

[image]

I noticed an `XHR` request to the following [endPoint](https://r.cnki.net/KNS/request/SearchHandler.ashx)

[image]

I think that the query pattern `QW=部队` encoded within `SearchStateJson` but I've no clue how that implemented !

Here's it:

```
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
```

Comment: I also think, however I'd include raw text request to question to give others an opportunity to inspect headers and try to answer.

Comment: @OlvinRoght thanks for the note. already added it.

Comment: Okay, I'd give you some small suggestions. Imagine that you have following secret key `b"\x43\x4e\x4b\x49\x40\x43\x4e\x4b"` *(it is randomly generated sequence, any similarity is purely coincidental)* and you want to use this as a key for DES encryption (ECB) with `b"\0" * 8` initialization vector. I believe that you won't use `pycryptodome` for [DES](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/des.htm). Just for educational purposes I'd say that decrypted data could probably have UTF-16 Big Endian encoding, so you could use `data.decode("utf-16-be")`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght That's the most crazy answer I've ever seen! i didn't imagine that at all! thanks a ton, now i will check if i can that API using pure JSON format. thank you very much.